# Finding the URL of a requested webpage

Tags: android, url, usb-debugging

Does anybody know how to 1) Detect if a web page is being opened/requested on an Android phone, and 2) Find the name/URL of that Webpage?
Thanks so much for any help.

UPDATE: The detection needs to be done on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this (detection) happens on your server (backend) website? If this is an ASP.Net site, you can start by querying the [user agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2). For example:

```
userAgent = Request.UserAgent;
if (userAgent.IndexOf("Android ") > -1) 
{
  // The browser is Android.
}
```